# Remove the vertical line in the chart js line chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I am using `Chart.js` to generate maps and have customised it to a good extent. But I am not able to remove the vertical grid line no matter what. Has anyone come across a situation like this? Help much appreciated.
[image]

**JavaScript**

```
    var ChartDataHome = {
        labels: ["", "NOV", "DEC", "JAN", "FEB"],
        datasets: [{
            strokeColor: "rgba(255.255,255,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(159,209,154,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1.00)",
            data: [4.5, 8.8, 7.5, 9.5, 7.8, 9]
        }]
    };

    var step = 2;
    var max = 10;
    var start = 0;

    ChartOptionsHome = {
        scaleLabel: "<%= value + ' K ' %>",
        pointDot: false,
        bezierCurve: false,
        scaleOverride: true,
        scaleSteps: 10,
        scaleSteps: Math.ceil((max - start) / step),
        scaleStepWidth: step,
        scaleStartValue: start,
        scaleShowGridLines: true,
        scaleGridLineWidth: 0,
        scaleGridLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.1)",
        datasetFill: false,
        animation: true,
        animationSteps: 60,
        scaleFontColor: "#ffffff",
        scaleFontSize: 14,
        scaleLineColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
        datasetStrokeWidth: 6,
        responsive: true,
    }

    if ($("#chartHome")[0]) {
        DrawTheChart(ChartDataHome, ChartOptionsHome, "chartHome", "Line");
    }
```

Answer (score 110, accepted):

The following applies to Chart.js 2.*.

If you only have one x-axis, whether the vertical grid lines (that are related to this x-axis) are displayed or not, is specified by the boolean value of `options.scales.xAxes[0].gridLines.display`. To be more precise, the following chart options disable the display of vertical grid lines for the single x-axis case.

```
options : {
    scales : {
        xAxes : [ {
            gridLines : {
                display : false
            }
        } ]
    }
}
```

Comment: how to turnoff for both X & Y from one place?

Comment: @techie_28 This should do the trick: `options : {
    scales : {
        xAxes : [ {
            gridLines : {
                display : false
            }
        } ],
        yAxes : [ {
            gridLines : {
                display : false
            }
        } ]
    }
}`

Comment: Yes but I was thinking `options : { scales : {gridLines : { display : false } } }` could disable both of them

Comment: @techie_28 I do not believe this would be desired (from the development perspective, there would be some serious implications of pushing an option to all children, if the option does not apply to the current option level, and maintaining an option in more that one option levels would be a waste of time). Each axis (do not forget about the possibility of multiple x-axes and y-axes too) has totally separate options. You could have two x-axes (that is why the `xAxes` is an array) and you could want to show the grid lines of the first x-axis, while hiding the grid lines of the second x-axis.

Answer (score 17):

There's a new global option that was released with the new version of Chart.js two days ago.

```
var options = {
    scaleShowVerticalLines: false
}
```

Comment: It's almost self explanatory, but to remove the horizontal lines, scaleShowHorizontalLines: false

Answer (score 16):

The Above answers seem outdated since they did not work in ChartJs 3.4.1 (probably lower versions as well) for me.

You can now use the following:

```
options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        grid: {
          display: false
        }
      },
    }        
}
```

It's self-explanatory, but to remove horizontal lines, you can replace the x with y.

Answer (score 4):

```
options : {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    gridLines: {
                        lineWidth: 0,
                        color: "rgba(255,255,255,0)"
                    }
                }]
            }
    };
Charts.js v2.0
```

Comment: Please add a description to explain your answer.

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

try `"scaleShowGridLines" : false,`

Comment: Won't that just disable both horizontal and vertical grid lines. I just want the vertical one to disappear.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can seperate x and y axis.

> ```
>   axes: {
>         xaxis: {
>             ticks: ticks,
>             tickOptions: {showGridline:false}
>         },
>         yaxis: {
>             tickOptions: {showGridline:true}
>         }
>     }
> ```

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score -3):

Simply write

```
 options:{  
 grid:{
    show: false
   }, 
}
```

It will solve your problem

Comment: This is incorrect, grid is not a property that is configurable on the root of the options, it also does not have a show prop

Comment: Hey, @faheem-riaz-bhatti. Your answer may indeed solve the problem, but unfortunately at StackOverflow they require more explanation to why this solves the problem.

Comment: This is not correct.