# How to remove column lines from chart.js

Tags: angularjs, charts

How can i remove vertical light-gray lines ( attached below) from angular-chart.js

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27182829/remove-the-vertical-line-in-the-chart-js-line-chart

Have you tried this ?

Comment: yes but it dsnt work

Comment: @АндрейГузюк share your code

Comment: I'm sorry first comment was helpful
it works 
thanks